# How to do pagination in aws dax when data is more than 1 MB for the given query key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dax, aws-dax

I am trying to read data from aws dax where the data is more than 1 MB for the given query key. How does the pagination works in this scenario!? I am not seeing much performance improvememt when data is more than 1 MB with respect to dax. Some suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

DAX has 2 caches, an `Item` and a `Query` cache.

The `Item` cache caches individual items based on their key.

The `Query` cache caches multiple items and the key is the request parameters as a whole. This cache serves both Query and Scan requests.

So when you make a paginated Scan, every page has a new ExclusiveStartKey and that is part of the cache key.

So if you make identical Scan requests with the number of items, ensuring the same ExclusiveStartKey per page, same FilterExpression, Limit etc... then you will make use of the Query cache, otherwise you'll be served by DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment! But will it be really efficient to use DAX when we have more than 1 MB of data? Because, even when I query with ExclusiveStartKey for each pagination query, the time that is being taken by DAX is almost the same as of the Dynamo DB. So how is DAX efficient in this scenario?

Comment: DAX still serves the data from memory, unlike DynamoDB, and with a cache hit on DAX you are ~10X faster. But with Scans which have multiple pages with frequently changing data, you reduce your chance of a cache hit.